# How to Enable the WordPress Toolbar Bar with WC Vendors and WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

When you use [WC Vendors](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-vendors/) your vendor gets a profile page which has the standard checkbox where they can choose to show the toolbar, but it doesn't work on the front end. How do you allow vendors to see this handy toolbar when viewing the site?

You can use the `woocommerce_disable_admin_bar` as follows but this shows the toolbar to your store customers too, which I don't want.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_disable_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find out what a vendor can do with 'current_user_can'. Then conditionally remove the main filter 'show_admin_bar'.

Make a child theme if you are not using one or a functions plugin. I recommend [WPClips](http://wpclips.net/).

```
/** 
 *
 * Show Admin Bar/Toolbar front end to Vendors 
 *
 */
function childthemeprefix_show_toolbar_vendors() { 

    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_product' ) ) {

        remove_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'wc_disable_admin_bar', 10, 1 );

    }

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'childthemeprefix_show_toolbar_vendors' );
```

Comment: Why `after_setup_theme` action hook? (Trying to learn, not arguing!)

Comment: I picked one https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference that ran early enough. Play around.

Comment: Fair enough! I like `wp` and `init`, but sometimes those aren't the right ones...

Comment: You can see on the https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference that init runs after the current user, after_setup_theme is the correct one for this situation.